# FTP: How to direct the client to not modify the bytes it received?

Tags: sockets, ftp, client-server, protocols, ftp-client

I am trying to implement an FTP server in C. However, as I send bytes to the client, the client automatically modifies the bytes in a certain way.

For example, I notice that the client changes 0D0A to 0A (CR+LF to LF). There are some other mysterious changes as well.

Is there a way that from the server side I can direct the client to not change any bytes it received? Or do I have to modify the bytes that I send in order to adjust to the client's conventions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FTP program found on unix systems has an "ascii" mode (the default) and a "binary" mode which must be used for binary transfers.

Possibly the issue you are having is due to the use of ascii mode.

Try using the "binary" command to switch modes.

Comment: It worked. Thank you for pointing out it is the client's responsibility to switch to binary mode.